# $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d,$ with $a > 0. $ If $f$ is strictly increasing, then the function $g(x) = f′ (x) −f′′(x) + f′′′(x)$ is

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **QUESTION:** Consider the function $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d,$ where $a, b, c$ and $d $ are real numbers with $a > 0. $ If $f$ is strictly increasing, then the function $g(x) = f′ (x) −f′′(x) + f′′′(x)$ is
>
> $(i)$ zero for some real $x$.
>
> $(ii)$ positive for all real $x$.
>
> $(iii)$ negative for all real $x$.
>
> $(iv)$ strictly increasing.

---

**MY ANSWER:** This is an easy question. I just want to know where I went wrong. This is what I did-

$$f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$$$$f''(x)=6ax+2b$$ and, $$f'''(x)=6a$$ therefore, $$g(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c-6ax-2b+6a$$ which is nothing but, $$g(x)=3ax^2+(2b-6a)x+(6a+c-2b)$$ therefore, it represents an upward opening parabola $(\because a>0)$. So we can see that the function is **not** strictly increasing *and* **not** always negative. Now whether or not the function attains zero, depends on the discriminant of the quadratic equation. But it comes out to be $$\sqrt{(2b-6a)^2-4(6a+c-2b)3a}$$ and this becomes too complicated.. also we have another piece of information that $f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c>0$. But I couldn't use it anywhere..

I am quite sure there are smarter ways to tackle this one.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your discriminant is negative. Hence g has no zeros and is strictly positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c \geq 0$, the discriminant of $f'$ should be negative:
$$4b^2 - 4\cdot 3a \cdot c = 4b^2 - 12ac \leq  0$$

Now the discriminant of $g$ equals 
$$(2b-6a)^2 - 4\cdot 3a \cdot (6a+c-2b) = 4b^2 - 24ab + 36a^2 - 72a^2 - 12ac + 24ab = 4b^2 - 12ac - 36a^2$$
but since $4b^2 - 12ac \leq 0$ and $-36a^2 < 0$, this discriminant is striclty negative.

This implies that $g(x) > 0$ for all $x$, since $g$ can't have any zeroes.

Comment: The discriminant may be zero as well, it just must not be negative.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe you're right. The discriminant of g will be strictly negative nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a multiple-choice question, you have the luxury to plug in values and arrive at the answer by process of elimination. For the easiest case, let $a=1,b=c=d=0.$ So $$g(x)=3x^2-6x+6$$ which is never $0.$ Thus $(ii)$ is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $g$ is an U-shaped parabola.  To calculate its vertex, solve 
$$g'(x_0)=0\iff f''(x_0)=f'''(x_0)$$
remembering that $f^{(4)}=0$. The second coordinate of the vertex is
$$g(x_0)=f'(x_0)-f''(x_0)+f'''(x_0)=f'(x_0)\geq0$$
as $f$ is strictly increasing.

If $f'(x_0)=0$ then $f$ has at $x_0$ a saddle point, that is, $f''(x_0)=0$, too, and that means $0=f''(x_0)=f'''(x_0)=6a>0$.

Comment: Excellent approach!!

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is strictly increasing, the reduced discriminant of $f^\prime$, i.e.:

$\frac{\Delta^\prime}{4} = b^2 - 3ac\;, $

satisfies $\frac{\Delta^\prime}{4} \leq 0$.

Now, the reduced discriminant of $g$, i.e.:

$\frac{\Delta}{4} = (b-3a)^2 - 3a(6a + c - 2b) = b^2 - 6ab + a^2 - 18a^2 - 3ac + 6ab = \frac{\Delta^\prime}{4} - 17a^2\;,$

satisfies $\frac{\Delta}{4} < 0$.
Therefore, $g$ has to have the same sign of $a$.